# Why css button background color doesn't change on hover, when there is a background color defined?

Tags: css

I have 2 buttons that should change the background color on hover. The ghost button does that, because it has got no background color defined, while full button keeps its original color.

I made it work by adding !important to hover and active state background color, but I believe that is just a quick and dirty solution, and there must be a better way?

```
.btn:hover,
.btn:active {
    background-color: #b05d14; 
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #fff;    
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
    border: 1px solid #e67e22;
    color: #e67e22;
}
```

Comment: Is it button or link? you cannot expect button to behave like link.

Comment: It's a button:

`<a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I’m hungry</a>`.

And another mutual class I am using is .btn:

`.btn:link,
.btn:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
}`

Comment: the hover should be placed after

Comment: Thank you, that helped! Haven't thought about the priority!